# Start an Activity from a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a Dialog Fragment attached to the Main Activity and is there any way we can start another Activity from the DialogFragment by a button Click.

My Intent call withing DialogFragment:

```
Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);

startActivity(i);
```

Have Registered the Second Activity in

### Manifest.xml

as below

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" 

          android:label="@string/app_name"  

          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

  <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="com.example.testjsoncall.SecondActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

  </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: why getActivity ?? use current context ..

Comment: start your activity with dialog fragment context

Comment: @PiyushGupta: I believe Fragment has no context associated with it. It just make use of the Parent's context. Here I am using the getActivity() which returns the context of MainActivity.

Comment: I know that... I have suggested to make global variable for it

Comment: @gunar: The problem is I'm facing a Null pointer exception.

Comment: @Anandaraja_Srinivasan: then please post the logcat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this helps you  :)

```
Intent i= new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);

context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Getting the Application Context from the DialogFragment did the Trick. Now I'm easily able to navigate to another Activity from the DialogFragment. Thx

Comment: the following error occurs when I try : java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = kidega.klebilgiteknolojiler.com.kidega.user_account.UserAccountFragment)  . can you help me please .

Answer (score 4):

`getActivity()` returns the context of your current Activity.
You need the context of the Dialog Fragment so get the context there.

So in your DialogFragment use MyActivity.this as your context

Hope this works